# R shiny wrong Date Output in reactive DataTable

Tags: r, shiny

My DataFrame shows the date output differently than the desired input. I read about the workaround using the `as.character()` command but this does not help:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
      dateInput("date", label = "Enter Date", value = "", format= "dd.mm.yyyy"),
      actionButton("Enter", label = "Submit"),
      hr(),
      dataTableOutput("dataframe")
      )

server <- function(input, output){
      df <- eventReactive(input$Enter, {
      data.frame(A = as.character(input$date))
      })

      output$dataframe <- renderDataTable(
      df()
      )
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

resulting in the following output:

[Output Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sz0H.png)

However, I would like to have the date to be in German date format `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the correct date, but another format
Try this one:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  dateInput("date", label = "Enter Date", value = "", format= "dd.mm.yyyy"),
  actionButton("Enter", label = "Submit"),
  hr(),
  dataTableOutput("dataframe")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  df <- eventReactive(input$Enter, {
    data.frame(A = as.character(format(input$date, "%d.%m.%Y")))
  })
  
  output$dataframe <- renderDataTable(
    df()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```